# Angular momentum and vector operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

I've been asked to prove the following expression:
$$[J^{2},[J^{2},\textbf{A}]]=2\hbar^2(\textbf{A}J^{2}+J^{2}\textbf{A})-4\hbar^2(\textbf{A}·\textbf{J})\textbf{J}$$
where $\textbf{A}$ is a vector operator and $\textbf{J}$ is the angular momentum operator. I guess I need to use the fact that $J^2|jm\rangle=j(j+1)\hbar^2|jm\rangle$, because the expression on the right has $\hbar^2$, but none of the things I've tried come close to the result I need.

Comment: To me it has nothing to do with the $|jm\rangle$ basis; it rather just uses commutation between those $J$ operators

Comment: BTW it feels not quite right to me; suppose ${\bf A}=(J_z,0,0)$, then the LHS only have $x$ component while the RHS's second term has all directions in ${\bf J}$.

Comment: What is $J_2$? Write down the commutation with J of a vector operator.

Answer (score 2):

A Vector operator can be defined by its commutation relation with the angular momentum. These are given by (setting $\hbar=1$)
$$[A_\mu,J_\nu]=i\epsilon_{\mu\nu\eta}A_\eta$$
Now, you can find
$$[J^2,A_\mu]=[J_\nu^2,A_\mu]=J_\nu[J_\nu,A_\mu]+[J_\nu,A_\mu]J_\nu$$
The right-hand side can be easily found. The next step is to find it's commutation with $J^2$ again:
$$[J^2,[J^2,A_\mu]]=J_\nu[J_\nu,[J^2,A_\mu]]+[J_\nu,[J^2,A_\mu]]J_\nu$$
Putting everything up should lead to desired result.

Comment: Welcome to 10k, and congratulations!

Comment: Thank you, Yay!!